# Performing aggregation on field values via Kibana not working

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

I am using Elasticsearch 5.4.1 and Kibana 5.4.1 . When I try to perform filter aggregations on field values like `fieldName:fieldValue` , I get no results.However when I only enter the `fieldValue` as a filter I obtain a list with matching `fieldValue` from all the fields. I am not able to figure out the issue.

I captured the request using chrome developer tools.Following request is fired when I use `fieldName:fieldValue`

```
{"index":"logstash-*","ignore_unavailable":true,"preference":1499662909171}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"analyze_wildcard":true,"query":"*"}},{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1499612400000,"lte":1499698799999,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}},"size":0,"_source":{"excludes":[]},"aggs":{"2":{"date_histogram":{"field":"@timestamp","interval":"1h","time_zone":"Asia/Tokyo","min_doc_count":1},"aggs":{"3":{"filters":{"filters":{"Success":{"query_string":{"query":"Response Status:200","analyze_wildcard":true}},"Failed":{"query_string":{"query":"-Response Status:200","analyze_wildcard":true}}}}}}}}}
```

But when I use only `fieldValue` below request is fired

```
{"index":"logstash-*","ignore_unavailable":true,"preference":1499662909171}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"analyze_wildcard":true,"query":"*"}},{"range":{"@timestamp":{"gte":1499612400000,"lte":1499698799999,"format":"epoch_millis"}}}],"must_not":[]}},"size":0,"_source":{"excludes":[]},"aggs":{"2":{"date_histogram":{"field":"@timestamp","interval":"1h","time_zone":"Asia/Tokyo","min_doc_count":1},"aggs":{"3":{"filters":{"filters":{"Success":{"query_string":{"query":"200","analyze_wildcard":true}},"Failed":{"query_string":{"query":"-200","analyze_wildcard":true}}}}}}}}}
```

I am not able to figure out the issue.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please attach your entire  request

Comment: @Lax Hi, I have updated the question.